# How many 6-digit integers greater than 321,000 can be formed such that each of the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 is used once in each 6-digit integer?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 6-digit integers greater than 321,000 can be formed such that each of the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 is used once in each 6-digit integer?

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, ten thousands, and thousands place (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) hundred thousands, ten thousands, and the thousands place to two (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, ten thousands, but the thousands place to four (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, ten thousands, but the thousands place to five (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, ten thousands, but the thousands place to six (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

---

So far we have $ 5 \cdot 3!$

---

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, but ten thousands is $4$, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, but ten thousands is $5$, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, but ten thousands is $6$, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, but ten thousands is $4$, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$

Keep original(fix) the hundred thousands, but ten thousands is $5$, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

---

Set the hundred thousands to four, fix the ten thousands, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

Set the hundred thousands to five, fix the ten thousands, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds,tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

Set the hundred thousands to six, fix the ten thousands, the thousands (all permutations of the hundreds, tens, and ones is $3!.$ ..

### This is a bad system.

There are cases I'm not enumerating, and I don't have a system to enumerate them that allows me to multi-task and count multiple things at the same time. How to continue to capture all cases?

Comment: Split the cases up as 1/ Leading digit is 4, 5, or 6, 2/ Leading digits are 34, 35, or 36, 3/ Leading digits are 32. What would you get for those?

Comment: @Calvin:  and do these as fractions of $6!$, so $\frac36+\frac45 \times \frac16$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. You need to permutate the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ to form a 6 digits number. There are two ways to count how many are greater than $321\ 000$ : directly or by counting those smaller.

**Directly**

Your idea is good, but you have to many cases and it is hard to keep track of what you are doing.

Hundred thousand $4, 5$ of $6$, then the rest of the number doesn't matter, it will be greater.
$$3\times 5!$$
Hundred thousand $3$, ten thousand $4, 5$ or $6$, then the rest of the number doesn't matter, it will be greater.
$$1\times3\times 4!$$
Hundred thousand $3$, ten thousand $2$, then the rest of the number doesn't matter, it will be greater. (The smallest such numbers is $321\ 456$)
$$1\times1\times 4!$$
Total
$$3\times 5!+1\times3\times 4!+1\times1\times 4! = 456$$

**Counting those smaller**

There is $6! = 720$ 6 digits numbers made with $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. How many of those are smaller than $321\ 000$?
Hundred thousand $1$ or $2$, then the rest of the number doesn't matter, it will be smaller.
$$2\times 5!$$
Hundred thousand $3$, then the ten thousand need to be $1$, the rest of the number doesn't matter..
$$1\times1\times 4!$$
Total smaller numbers
$$2\times 5! + 1\times1\times 4!=264$$
Answer
$$720-264=456$$

Answer (score 2):

- Each starting digit gives $5$ possible **two digit starts**$\,\rightarrow 30$ total
- Five each starting with $1$ or $2$ are "bad" as is one starting with $32$, leaving $30-11=19$ "good" two digit starts
- Thus there are $19\times4! = 456$ "good" numbers

Comment: but what about 41xxxx, 51xxxx and 61xxxx?

Comment: @somebody: Good catch, corrected !

Comment: What's a "five each"? @trueblueanil

Comment: @Lasuiqw: Edited for greater clarity, "Five each" two digit starts